# Redirect Multiple Paths to external URLs

Tags: traefik, rancher

i have a problem redirecting multiple paths with traefik to multiple Destinations.

Because of software legacy reasons i have to redirect some paths behind my application to external urls.
My app is running in rancher and i'm using rancher labels to configure traefik with it:

```
traefik.enable: 'true'
traefik.app.backend: app
traefik.app.frontend.redirect.entryPoint: https
traefik.app.frontend.rule: 'Host: app.url'
traefik.app.protocol: http
traefik.app.port: '8080'
traefik.support.backend: support
traefik.support.protocol: https
traefik.support.frontend.redirect.regex: ^https?://app.url/support/(.*)
traefik.support.frontend.redirect.replacement: https://other.support.url    
traefik.support.port: '8080'
```

However https://app.url/support does not redirect to https://other.support.url and i got an 404 Error.

If i had only on URL to redirct i'd add an redirect at entrypoint level of https entrypoint.
But like i suggest entrypoint doesn't support multiple redirects.

```
[entryPoints.https]
 address = ":443"
 [entryPoints.https.redirect]
  regex = "^https://app.url/support"
  replacement = "https://other.support.url"
```

How can i achieve this using latest traefik 1.6.4 and Rancher 1.6.x.
Or is it even possible ?

I don't wan't to use another proxy like nginx only for redirection that adds a lot of complications and i find the configuration with labels very comfortabel and transparent.

Any ideas anyone?

Answer (score 1):

You can move the rules into frontends. Since frontends seem to need a backend defined, just define it even though it will never be called.

```
[backends]
  [backends.fake]
    [backends.fake.servers.s1]
      url="http://1.2.3.4"

[frontends]
[frontends.r1]
  backend = "fake"
  [frontends.r1.redirect]
    regex = "^http://foo.bar/(.*)"
    replacement = "http://mydomain1/$1"
    permanent = false
[frontends.r2]
  backend = "fake"
  [frontends.r2.redirect]
    regex = "^http://bar.blech/(.*)"
    replacement = "http://mydomain2/$1"
    permanent = false
```